# Jackson serialize object as key of map

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

Hi I'm facing problem with serialization of map where key is an custom class.

```
data class KeyClass(val id: Int, val name: String) {
    fun toJSON() = "\"KeyClass\": {\"id\":$id,\"name\":\"$name\"}"
}
```

Invocation:

```
 fun method(): Map<KeyClass, List<Something>> = ...
```

My jackson Serializer ofc I'm also adding this as module in objectMapper:

```
class KeyClassSerializer : JsonSerializer<KeyClass>() {
    override fun serialize(value: KeyClass, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider) {
        gen.writeRawValue(value.toJSON())
    }

}

class KeyClassSerializerModule : SimpleModule() {
    init {
        addKeySerializer(KeyClass::class.java, KeyClassSerializer())
    }
}
```

And JSON I'm receiving is:

```
"\"KeyClass\": {\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Thomas\"}" : [Something:...]
```

I mean the value of map is serialized correctly but key isn't.

Comment: What is the result you expect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the expected result is :

```
"KeyClass": {
  "id": 1,
  "name":"Thomas"
} : [...]
```

But it's not valid Json. You can still do something like :

```
{
  "key" : {
      "id": 1,
      "name":"Thomas"
  },
  "value" : [...]
}
```

Comment: But for this I need to write serialize for Map<KeyClass, List<Something>>

Comment: No, create a data class KV (key: KeyClass, value: List<Something>), no need for custom serializer.